# Is it possible to connect disk via regular eSATA cable to eSATA powered port?

Tags: external-hard-drive, cable, esata

I have external hard drive that is powered from AC adapter and a regular SATA to eSATA cable (SATA goes to disk, eSATA to computer).

Is it possible to connect it to powered eSATA port (with regular eSATA cable) on notebook without causing any damage to the disk (that is already powered)?

Answer (score 0):

probably - electrically the ports are identical

Answer (score -1):

Scroll down to ESATA to see what differences there are.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA

There is a new specification eSATAp that has power, scroll down to "SATA in comparison to other buses" on the same page.

Comment: -1 for posting without answering. Since you've already found the Wikipedia entry, couldn't you give us a one-sentence summary? Or perhaps a yes-or-no answer?

Comment: Hi Moab, I did post an answer but deleted it again exactly because I didn't think it was good enough. I didn't give an answer in my above comment to your answer - that's not what the comments are for.

Comment: Hey torbengb, No offense taken, but mine was a post that linked to the answer, I don't always spoon feed answers to posters here, sometimes its better that they learn for themselves especially when there may be no simple binary answer. I don't strive to be perfect here on super user, sometimes my answers are a bit in the grey area which is acceptable to me.